# Ios ( Xcode ): Resize splash screen icon according to device screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, splash-screen, launch-screen

Im trying to create a splash/ launch screen for ios. For that Im using Launchscreen storyboard. The splash screen is quite simple containing one image. When I review it in iphone size it looks fine, but it doesnt seem to adjust to bigger (or smaller) devices (ipad -> screenshot, older iphone). How do I create sort of responsiveness of the image to the actual device size?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD8Sm.png)

Comment: How would you like to show the image? fullscreen? center? please embed your desired image.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should use auto-layout to achieve the responsiveness that you're looking for.

If you want it to be full screen, you may constraint all edges of the image view to all edges of the superview.

If you want it to be centered, you can set the content type of the image view or use the center constraints for the layout.

If you want it to resize larger or smaller corresponds to the different sizes, you can use autoresizing feature from the size ispector panel.